# yaml library on linux doesn't decode what it's encoded

Tags: haskell, yaml

decode / encode:

```
yDecode :: FromJSON iFromJSONable ⇒ FilePath → IO iFromJSONable
yDecode fnm = do
  ymlData ← BS.readFile fnm
  return $ fromMaybe (error "Can't parse from YAML") (decode ymlData)

yEncode :: ToJSON iToJSONable ⇒ FilePath → iToJSONable → IO()
yEncode fnm dat = BS.writeFile fnm $ encode dat
```

I create config with this encode and it creates just fine but when I'm reading it - I'm getting this error: `Can't parse from YAML` - on windows same code works fine and there I just can't understand what is possibly wrong?

Comment: maybe it's one of this stupid line-ending thing - how does the YAML file look like? Can you try copy&pasting it to a new file (on linux) and retry?

Comment: @Carsten copy&pasting doesn't work even if I copy config from windows, but sure `[]` config works / btw not sure currently but looks like windows is using `LF` and linux is using `CRLF` there :S

Comment: `[]` as in empty file? ... It's really hard to tell if you don't give us more details on the file and on the type you finally decode into

Comment: @Carsten [] is empty yaml config. here is paste of file https://bpaste.net/show/31c112c04879 and config https://gist.github.com/Heather/5231925d6c123c92d576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases of `Nothing`, it's best to grab more information by using `decodeEither`/`decodeEither'`. The left side of the either value will contain an error message telling you where the failure occurs. If you switch over, you'll see that the parsing is failing due to the `error "Can't parse Repository from YAML"` line (see `attempt1` below). It's encountering something besides an Object!

It's best then to see what the heck the YAML package is decoding to then, by decoding to the type we know that has to succeed — Value. Decoding, we get this (see `attempt2` below):

```
Right (Array (fromList [Object (fromList [("group",Null),("branches",Array (fromList [String "master"])),("hash",Null),("clean",Null),("location",String "/home/gentoo-haskell"),("enabled",Null),("root",Null),("postRebuild",Null),("upstream",String "upstream master"),("task",String "rebase"),("positive",Null)])]))
```

It appears the root data structure is an Array and not an Object. There are lots of ways to fix this, and I chose a hacky one.

```
parseJSON (Array array) = parseJSON (array ! 0)
```

This makes the program work! I pasted my code below. (Apologies for the use of lens; I use it to convert between strings and bytestrings for quick scripts like these. Your program will of course work perfectly fine without it.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Lib where

import Control.Lens
import Data.ByteString
import Data.ByteString.Lens
import Data.Vector
import Data.Yaml

data Repository = Repository
    { location      :: String
    , task          :: String
    , branches      :: [String]
    , upstream      :: String
    , enabled       :: Maybe Bool
    , root          :: Maybe Bool
    , positive      :: Maybe Bool
    , clean         :: Maybe Bool
    , postRebuild   :: Maybe [String]
    , syncGroup     :: Maybe String
    , hash          :: Maybe String
    } deriving (Show, Eq)


instance FromJSON Repository where
    parseJSON (Object v) = Repository <$>
                           v .:  "location"     <*>
                           v .:  "task"         <*>
                           v .:  "branches"     <*>
                           v .:  "upstream"     <*>
                           v .:? "enabled"      <*>
                           v .:? "root"         <*>
                           v .:? "positive"     <*>
                           v .:? "clean"        <*>
                           v .:? "postRebuild"  <*>
                           v .:? "group"        <*>
                           v .:? "hash"
    parseJSON (Array array) = parseJSON (array ! 0)

raw :: String
raw = unlines [
    "- group: null",
    "  branches:",
    "  - master",
    "  hash: null",
    "  clean: null",
    "  location: /home/gentoo-haskell",
    "  enabled: null",
    "  root: null",
    "  postRebuild: null",
    "  upstream: upstream master",
    "  task: rebase",
    "  positive: null"]

attempt1 :: Either ParseException Repository
attempt1 = decodeEither' (raw ^. packedChars)

attempt2 :: Either ParseException Value
attempt2 = decodeEither' (raw ^. packedChars)
```

Comment: my actual error there is `failed to parse field enabled: expected Bool, encountered Null`

Comment: and I'm still being not sure what is the reason for it :/ bug with maybies?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.10.0.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-Instances.html - should be related but can't dig into actual problem for now